# jquery accordion loading via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, accordion

I've got an accordion in the container:

```
<div id="address_results"></div>
```

Now I fill in the **html** (an accordion) via an **ajax** call. It works fine but only by the first **ajax** call. By the second, third, etc. call, the animation of the accordion doesn't work.

```
// Ajax request
        $(this).submit(function() {
            var postal = $(o.postalDiv).val();

            $.getJSON(o.url,{ action: o.action, id: o.id, postal: postal } , function(json) {
                var result = json.content;
                var addresses = result['addresses'];
                var strXML = result['xml'];

                outputHtml(addresses);

            });
            return false;
        });

        // Ajax request success
        function outputHtml(addresses) {

            $(o.resultsDiv).html(addresses);

            // Generate the accordion
            $(o.resultsDiv).accordion({

                autoHeight: false,
                header:'div.toggler',
                active: false,
                collapsible: true
            });
```

When I remove/append the `div` before I fill in the accordion:

```
$('#addresses_results').remove();
$('#reswrapper').append('<div id="address_results"></div>');
```

then it works fine. But this can be the right way?

(sorry my English, is not my native language)
thanks!

Comment: Does `o.resultsDiv` and `address_results` refer same div?

Comment: Have a look at this blog entry .. http://www.springenwerk.com/2008/07/jquery-ui-accordion-callback-and.html if it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
 $('#addresses_results').accordion('destroy').accordion();
```

Comment: If I destroy the accordion first then

Answer (score 1):

The following line doesn't work, because by the first ajax call the accordion isn't exists.

```
$('#addresses_results').accordion('destroy').accordion();
```

The solution is to check if the accordion already exists:

```
 if ($(o.resultsDiv).hasClass('ui-accordion')) {
     $(o.resultsDiv).accordion('destroy');
  }
```

The whole Solution:

```
    (function ($) {

    $.fn.address = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            url:           '/ajax.php',
            action:        'fmd',
            id:             0,
            resultsDiv:    '#address_results',
            postalDiv:     '#address_postal'
        };
        var o = $.extend(defaults,options);

        // Ajax request
        $(this).submit(function() {
            var postal = $(o.postalDiv).val();

            $.getJSON(o.url,{ action: o.action, id: o.id, postal: postal } , function(json) {
                var result = json.content;
                var addresses = result['addresses'];
                var strXML = result['xml'];

                outputHtml(addresses);

            });
            return false;
        });

        // Ajax request success
        function outputHtml(addresses) {

            $(o.resultsDiv).html(addresses);

            // Check if the accordion already exist. if so destroy it
            if ($(o.resultsDiv).hasClass('ui-accordion')) {
                $(o.resultsDiv).accordion('destroy');
            }

            // Generate the accordion
            $(o.resultsDiv).accordion({
                autoHeight: false,
                header:'div.toggler',
                active: false,
                collapsible: true
            });
        }

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks!